# Google Cloud Messaging Server key whitelist IP addresses with auto scaling

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating my AWS beanstalk application to use GCM on the server side for android push update. However, when i'm setting up the server key, it prompts me for a set of whitelist server IP.

My question is, if my application is under AWS's auto scaling system, how does the whitelist work? Should I be manually entering the IP addresses of all the EC2 instances?

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to fill in the set of whitelist server IPs. It's optional.

If you know all the potential IP addresses your server may run on, you can specify a list of IP addresses or subnets (such as 192.168.12.0/23). Otherwise, keep it empty.

Answer (score 1):

From Googles documentation I believe you can also do this:

Use the CIDR range 0.0.0.0/0, which allows all external IP addresses to connect.